# Unable to identify cause of: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: pandas, valueerror, pandas-loc, isin

**Background:**
I have a script that makes a daily API call for financial data, returns the data as a JSON object, saves it into a pandas `df` before doing some manipulation on the `df` and finally saving as a .`csv` before being uploaded into a system.

**Issue:**
My script worked fine until recently when presumably new data entered the JSON object, and I now receive the following `ValueError` -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JONNY~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17600/3701323957.py in <module>
     13 
     14 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 15     main()

C:\Users\JONNY~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17600/3701323957.py in main()
      1 # Function that writes Exceptions Report and API Response as a consolidated .xlsx file.
      2 def main():
----> 3     financial_accounts_df = dataframe_transformation()
      4 
      5 #   Writing dataframe to .csv

C:\Users\JONNY~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17600/203167952.py in dataframe_transformation()
     19   # Step 3 - remove the parent rows, leaving only children
     20     rows_to_remove = financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'])
---> 21     financial_accounts_df.loc[financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].values),
     22                               'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'] = financial_accounts_df.loc[rows_to_remove, 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].to_numpy()
     23     financial_accounts_df = financial_accounts_df[~rows_to_remove]

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    714 
    715         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 716         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    717 
    718     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1686         if take_split_path:
   1687             # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1688             self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1689         else:
   1690             self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

~\.conda\envs\JPDevelopment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1741                     return self._setitem_with_indexer((pi, info_axis[0]), value[0])
   1742 
-> 1743                 raise ValueError(
   1744                     "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1745                     "when setting with an iterable"

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

**The script:** I have removed the functions that call the API and instead wrote a function that will load the Sample Datasets offered below and simulate the `ValueError` I am receiving. Note: not all the libraries dependencies are being used:

```
# Importing depedencies
from configparser import ConfigParser
import datetime as date
import datetime as dt
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests as requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import time
import json 
import jsonpath_ng as jp
import enlighten
import numpy as np

# Function to read API response / JSON Object
def response_writer():
    with open('test_not_working.json') as f:
        api_response = json.load(f)
        return api_response
    
# api_response = response_writer()
api_response = response_writer()

# Set an auto_id_field which appears later as "json_path" in pandas dataframe columns
jp.jsonpath.auto_id_field = 'json_path'

def unpack_response():
    # Create a dataframe from JSON response
    expr = jp.parse('$..children.[*].json_path')
    data = [{'json_path': m.value, **m.datum.value} for m in expr.find(api_response)]
    df = pd.json_normalize(data).sort_values('json_path', ignore_index=True)

    # Append a portfolio column
    df['portfolio'] = df.loc[df.json_path.str.contains(r'total\.children\.\[\d+]$'), 'name']
    df['portfolio'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    # Mapping column headers appropriately from the JSON
    trans = {'columns.' + c['key']: c['display_name'] for c in api_response['meta']['columns']}
    cols = ['json_path', 'name', 'FinServ__SourceSystemId__c', 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c', 'FinServ__FinancialAccountNumber__c', 'FinServ__OpenDate__c', 'FinServ__CloseDate__c', 'Display_Name__c',
           'JP_Custodian__c', 'Online_Status__c', 'Custodian_Account_Name__c', 'Management_Style__c', 'Portfolio_Type__c', 'Advisory_Firm__c', 'FinServ__Balance__c', 'Target_Cash__c', 'Target_Cash_Notes__c']

    df = df.rename(columns=trans)[cols]
    # Then renaming those that could be phrased better.
    df.rename(columns={'name': 'Name'}, inplace=True)

    return df

# Function that takes df and performs varios manipulation, before saving in dataframe
def dataframe_transformation():
#   Calling function that returns both dataframes
    financial_accounts_df = unpack_response()
    
#   Limiting character length of Name column
    financial_accounts_df['Name'] = financial_accounts_df['Name'].str[:80]

  # Removing Directly Owned Rows
    financial_accounts_df = financial_accounts_df[financial_accounts_df['Name'].str.contains("Directly Owned")==False]

#   Changing 'Holding Account' name to 'Name'
    financial_accounts_df = financial_accounts_df.rename(columns={'Holding Account': 'Name'})

#   Creating RecordTypeID Column and setting initial value of '0123h000000FPFjAAO'
    financial_accounts_df['RecordTypeID'] = '0123h000000FPFjAAO'

#   Step 1 - Search for 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c' values in 'FinServ__SourceSystemId__c' column.
#   Step 2 - for rows where Step 1 is true, mirror 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c' value to match.
#   Step 3 - remove the parent rows, leaving only children 
    rows_to_remove = financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'])
    financial_accounts_df.loc[financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].values),
                              'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'] = financial_accounts_df.loc[rows_to_remove, 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].to_numpy()
    financial_accounts_df = financial_accounts_df[~rows_to_remove]
    
    
#   Duplicating the 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c' column and renaming duplication 'FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c'
    financial_accounts_df['FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c'] = financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c']

#   Moving position of newly created column to index position 3 for ease of comparison
    first_column = financial_accounts_df.pop('FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c')
    financial_accounts_df.insert(3, 'FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c', first_column)
    
#   Dropping the first df column / json_path
    financial_accounts_df = financial_accounts_df.iloc[: , 1:]

    return financial_accounts_df

# Function that writes dataframe to csv file
def main():
    financial_accounts_df = dataframe_transformation()
    
#   Writing dataframe to .csv
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    filename = 'financial_accounts_'+timestr+'.csv'

    # financial_accounts_df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
    financial_accounts_df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
    
    print(f' Filename:',filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Challenges identifying issue:**
In theory the returned data will be similar and the only change will be additional rows of data entering the JSON object.
What concerns me is that I can't think of a solution that would allow me to identify what row of data (7000 rows in total) is causing this issue / what row of data shows my code for what it is (flawed in someway).
I appreciate the information I am providing is light, however does anyone have suggestions about how I can either isolate the offending row of data in the pandas `df` and/or have any idea how my code might be flawed and causing this issue?

**Sample Data**:
Here are 2x samples, one that works with the function and the other that does not. I hope this helps assist me triangulate the issue -

**Sample 1 (Working)** - this runs through the function without issue:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "key": "node_id",
        "display_name": "FinServ__SourceSystemId__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "direct_owner_id",
        "display_name": "Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "bottom_level_holding_account_number",
        "display_name": "FinServ__FinancialAccountNumber__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_account_open_date_425913",
        "display_name": "FinServ__OpenDate__c",
        "output_type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_close_date_411160",
        "display_name": "FinServ__CloseDate__c",
        "output_type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "key": "display_name",
        "display_name": "Display_Name__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_jp_custodian_305769",
        "display_name": "JP_Custodian__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "online_status",
        "display_name": "Online_Status__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351",
        "display_name": "Custodian_Account_Name__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_management_style_295599",
        "display_name": "Management_Style__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_portfolio_type_295600",
        "display_name": "Portfolio_Type__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_advisor_302684",
        "display_name": "Advisory_Firm__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_test1_679151",
        "display_name": "FinServ__Balance__c",
        "output_type": "Number"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547",
        "display_name": "Target_Cash__c",
        "output_type": "Number"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522",
        "display_name": "Target_Cash_Notes__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      }
    ],
    "groupings": [
      {
        "key": "holding_account",
        "display_name": "Holding Account"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "portfolio_views",
    "attributes": {
      "total": {
        "name": "Total",
        "columns": {
          "online_status": null,
          "_custom_test1_679151": null,
          "direct_owner_id": null,
          "_custom_account_open_date_425913": null,
          "display_name": null,
          "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": null,
          "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": null,
          "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
          "bottom_level_holding_account_number": null,
          "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
          "_custom_advisor_302684": null,
          "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": null,
          "_custom_management_style_295599": null,
          "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
          "node_id": null
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "entity_id": 10663945,
            "name": "10 Laverockbank LLC Hold (668168788)",
            "grouping": "holding_account",
            "columns": {
              "online_status": "Online",
              "_custom_test1_679151": 5045.08,
              "direct_owner_id": "10710095",
              "_custom_account_open_date_425913": "2021-05-14",
              "display_name": "10 Madison LLC Hold",
              "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": "10 MADISON LLC | &HOLDING | LLC",
              "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": "Cash Management",
              "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
              "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "668168788",
              "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
              "_custom_advisor_302684": "Advisory Name",
              "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": "Custodian Name",
              "_custom_management_style_295599": "Holding",
              "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
              "node_id": "10663945"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": []
}
```

**Sample 2 (`ValueError`)** - this creates a `ValueError` and is an example of 1/2 dozen `children` that throw up the `ValueError`:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "key": "node_id",
        "display_name": "FinServ__SourceSystemId__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "direct_owner_id",
        "display_name": "Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "bottom_level_holding_account_number",
        "display_name": "FinServ__FinancialAccountNumber__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_account_open_date_425913",
        "display_name": "FinServ__OpenDate__c",
        "output_type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_close_date_411160",
        "display_name": "FinServ__CloseDate__c",
        "output_type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "key": "display_name",
        "display_name": "Display_Name__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_jp_custodian_305769",
        "display_name": "JP_Custodian__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "online_status",
        "display_name": "Online_Status__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351",
        "display_name": "Custodian_Account_Name__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_management_style_295599",
        "display_name": "Management_Style__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_portfolio_type_295600",
        "display_name": "Portfolio_Type__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_advisor_302684",
        "display_name": "Advisory_Firm__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_test1_679151",
        "display_name": "FinServ__Balance__c",
        "output_type": "Number"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547",
        "display_name": "Target_Cash__c",
        "output_type": "Number"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522",
        "display_name": "Target_Cash_Notes__c",
        "output_type": "Word"
      }
    ],
    "groupings": [
      {
        "key": "holding_account",
        "display_name": "Holding Account"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "portfolio_views",
    "attributes": {
      "total": {
        "name": "Total",
        "columns": {
          "online_status": null,
          "_custom_test1_679151": null,
          "direct_owner_id": null,
          "_custom_account_open_date_425913": null,
          "display_name": null,
          "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": null,
          "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": null,
          "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
          "bottom_level_holding_account_number": null,
          "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
          "_custom_advisor_302684": null,
          "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": null,
          "_custom_management_style_295599": null,
          "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
          "node_id": null
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "entity_id": 15425904,
            "name": " WF Rev Tr US Eq 2 Wrapper (E79508009)",
            "grouping": "holding_account",
            "columns": {
              "online_status": "Offline",
              "_custom_test1_679151": 99.86,
              "direct_owner_id": "7400472",
              "_custom_account_open_date_425913": null,
              "display_name": null,
              "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": null,
              "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": null,
              "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
              "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "E79508009",
              "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
              "_custom_advisor_302684": null,
              "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": null,
              "_custom_management_style_295599": null,
              "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
              "node_id": "15425904"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "entity_id": 13845019,
                "name": "WF Rev Tr US Eq 2 (E79508009)",
                "grouping": "holding_account",
                "columns": {
                  "online_status": "Online",
                  "_custom_test1_679151": 99.86,
                  "direct_owner_id": "15425904",
                  "_custom_account_open_date_425913": null,
                  "display_name": "WF Rev Tr US Eq 2",
                  "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": "RYAN HUDSON REVOCABLE TRUST",
                  "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": "Core Portfolio: Liquid",
                  "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
                  "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "E79508009",
                  "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
                  "_custom_advisor_302684": "Advisory Name",
                  "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": "Custodian Name",
                  "_custom_management_style_295599": "US Core Tax-Loss Harvesting",
                  "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
                  "node_id": "13845019"
                },
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "entity_id": 15425937,
                "name": "WF Rev Tr US Eq 2 Non-Discretionary (E79508009)",
                "grouping": "holding_account",
                "columns": {
                  "online_status": "Offline",
                  "_custom_test1_679151": 0,
                  "direct_owner_id": "15425904",
                  "_custom_account_open_date_425913": null,
                  "display_name": null,
                  "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": "E79508009",
                  "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": "L.I.F.E. Assets",
                  "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
                  "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "E79508009",
                  "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
                  "_custom_advisor_302684": "N/A - Client Directed",
                  "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": "",
                  "_custom_management_style_295599": "External",
                  "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
                  "node_id": "15425937"
                },
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "entity_id": 10663945,
            "name": "10 Laverockbank LLC Hold (668168788)",
            "grouping": "holding_account",
            "columns": {
              "online_status": "Online",
              "_custom_test1_679151": 5045.08,
              "direct_owner_id": "10710095",
              "_custom_account_open_date_425913": "2021-05-14",
              "display_name": "10 Madison LLC Hold",
              "_custom_custodian_account_name_487351": "10 MADISON LLC | &HOLDING | LLC",
              "_custom_portfolio_type_295600": "Cash Management",
              "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
              "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "668168788",
              "_custom_new_target_cash_balance_gwl_453547": null,
              "_custom_advisor_302684": "Advisory Name",
              "_custom_jp_custodian_305769": "Custodian Name",
              "_custom_management_style_295599": "Holding",
              "_custom_target_cash_notes_341522": null,
              "node_id": "10663945"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": []
}
```

Comment: Can you load in the JSON as a python dict with "with open("file.json") as f: data = json.load(f)" to verify the JSON is valid (has correct formatting), and then write a function to iterate through the whole thing to error-check it? Its hard to give an answer without sample data, a JSON with dummy data that fails the function would help.

Comment: Sure thing @HershJoshi I have add 2x samples from the original dataset. I can confirm the JSON objects are valid; I ran them through a validator to ensure this.

Comment: I still can not figure out how the `json` data become `DataFrame`, could you give us a little example?

Comment: @FavorMylikes - thanks for your feedback. I have expanded my question to include a executable script. Note: I have removed functions that call the API and instead wrote a quick function that will load the Sample Datasets I have provided if you save them at JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your code for about half-hour, it is too complex for the structure and the syntax, which is not a good coding habit for you.

I'll try to understand as much as possible what you want to do.

Here is some advice for you.

1. If the json data you have downloaded and it super large, `json path` is not a good way to parse it, this will consume a lot of memory, or, If it is from `requests` like an HTTP response, `json path` is ok, cause, usually the data returned is not so large.
2. Fixing the order of columns and renaming it is not a suitable way. Cause you can not make sure the order is not the same every time, especially for the key of a `dict` object. Not to mention the content returned from the server, which means you can not control the content.
3. For your question

```py
financial_accounts_df.loc[financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].values),
                              'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'] = financial_accounts_df.loc[rows_to_remove, 'Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].to_numpy()
```

The first index `financial_accounts_df['Addepar_Direct_Owner_ID__c'].isin(financial_accounts_df['FinServ__SourceSystemId__c'].values)` is `[True, False, False, False]`

And the second index, `rows_to_remove`, is `[False, True, True, False]`

It is the main reason for your value error exception.

And, I don't know how you will handle the nest `children` element, but you have to make sure the number of `Ture` for each index is equal.